# I want to summarize column values ​with sql

Tags: mysql

| ID | title | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | a |
| 1 | test | b |
| 2 | test2 | c |
| 2 | test2 | d |
| 3 | test3 | e |
| 3 | test3 | f |

I have a table like above in mysql.
I want to group the "category" with the same ID as below.

| ID | title | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | a,b |
| 2 | test2 | c,d |
| 3 | test3 | e,f |

I want to achieve this with mysql.
In that case, what kind of sql statement should be executed?

Comment: You can't solve this problem in a deterministic way, if you don't have a rationale to order your categories.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  max(title) as title, 
  group_concat(category) as category
FROM a
GROUP BY ID
```

You can also only repeat distinct values as such

```
SELECT
  ID,
  group_concat(distinct title) as title,
  group_concat(distinct category) as category
FROM a
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
SELECT ID, title, group_concat(category) as category
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID, title
```

You can also use `SEPARATOR` and `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function :

```
SELECT ID, title, group_concat(category ORDER BY category ASC SEPARATOR ',') as category
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID, title
```

Comment: Question was to group by ID, not it and title. In the example the title and ID correspond, but it is not up to us to assume this will always be the case.